# Is the draft option supposed to work in the poster class?

Tags: posters, draft

I am making a poster, but don't yet have all the images, so wanted to use draft to ignore all the `\includegraphics` commands for now. However, that does not seem to work.

Comment: Does using `demo` option will work? Otherwise you should provide an example.

Answer (score 2):

The `draft` option for `graphics`, as documented, still requires the images (or at least the size information) so that LaTeX can leave the correct space. It just suppresses the actual image inclusion.